# Mongoose deep populate with Mongoosastic

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-populate, mongoosastic

I have read many of the mongoose deep populate docs and articles, but I can't seem to get it to work in this case, but I have a feeling it is because when the data was stored, `dealSchema` was without an id. Thoughts?

Because of the goal here of using mongoosastic and indexing the information in elasticsearch, I'm passing in the populate params with plugin.

```
//mongoose version 4.8.0

var dealSchema = new Schema({
    deal: {type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Deal'},
    discounts: [discountSchema]
}, {_id:false});


var offerSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    description: String,
    partner: {type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Partner'},
    venues: [{type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Venue'}],
    deals: [dealSchema],
    modified: Date,
    created: Date
});


//=================================================//
mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/production');
offerSchema.plugin(mongoosastic, {
  hosts: [ 'http://127.0.0.1:9200' ],
    index: 'myIndex',
    type: 'offer',
    populate: [
        { path: 'partner', model: 'Partner', select: 'name' },
        { path: 'venues', model: 'Venue', select: 'name' },
        { path: 'deals.deal', model: 'Deal', select: 'name' }
    ]
});

///////// indexed data in ES ///////////
// 1. partners and venues are populated as expected, name only.
// 2. deals.deal is not populated as intended

{
  "_index": "myIndex",
  "_type": "offer",
  "_id": "568454a104439f0300a57e86",
  "_score": 2.1182644,
  "_source": {
    "name": "offer name",
    "description": "This is an offer.",
    "partner": {
      "_id": "566ddbf61e11f0030020fcc5",
      "name": "partner one"
    },
    "venues": [
      {
        "_id": "566df15d1e11f00300211c13",
        "name": "venue one"
      },
      {
        "_id": "566df2f1b6e09103003595a6",
        "name": "venue two"
      }
    ],
    "deals": [
      {
        "deal": "566df755b6e091030035cbed",
        "discounts": [
          {
            "amount": 0,
            "attribute": "566ddeff1e11f0030020fccf"
          },
          {
            "amount": 0,
            "attribute": "566ddef91e11f0030020fcce"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "modified": "2016-05-31T23:04:55.476Z",
    "created": "2015-12-30T22:03:13.354Z"
  }
}
```

Comment: what are you getting and what are you expecting as a result. This question seems incomplete

Comment: Apologize. I am getting a populated Venue and Partner, name only as expected. However, the deals.deal remains just an I'd. No population and no errors. I'll post the response as soon as I get home.

Comment: are you sure that deal exist in Deal collection?

Comment: SOLVED: I just needed to remove my elasticsearch index and re-import using { path: 'deals.deal', model: 'Deal', select: 'name' } shown above ... thanks for the continued responses Ravi.

Comment: @RaviShankar: please do not use [solved] in titles here - we do not use them. Thanks.

Comment: @halfer okay, i thought this way others will know that its solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below works. I needed to remove my elasticsearch index before re-running.

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/production');
    offerSchema.plugin(mongoosastic, {
      hosts: [ 'http://127.0.0.1:9200' ],
        index: 'myIndex',
        type: 'offer',
        populate: [
            { path: 'partner', model: 'Partner', select: 'name' },
            { path: 'venues', model: 'Venue', select: 'name' },
            { path: 'deals.deal', model: 'Deal', select: 'name' }
        ]
    });
```

Comment: Well I used to same code and it doesn't populate when I query elasticsearch created index.

It still returns me the ObjectId and not the actual referenced data. Do I need to create a custom mapping or any such thing for `ref` types with mongoosastic/mongoose.

Comment: It is not working, it is returning the same ObjectId

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

Populating this way, actually populates the `deals.deal` as expected. So perhaps this is a `mongoosastic` issue when declaratively populating.

```
Offer.findOne({'_id': '568454a104439f0300a57e86'}).populate('deals.deal').exec(function(err, doc){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(doc));
});
```